# field content type from an SPListItem?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, c#-3.0, moss

how do I get the field content type (i.e. ImageFieldContent, etc.) from an SPListItem?

Answer (score 0):

To get the content type of an item try oItem["ContentType"].tosString() (where oItem is your SPListItem object)

To get the type of the columns within an SPListsItem then you will have to loop through the oItem.Fields and get the FieldvalueType.
eg

```
foreach (SPField oField in oItem.Fields)
        {
         Console.WriteLine(oField.FieldValueType);
        }
```

**Note:** FieldValueType: Gets the value type of the field when the field type has its own value type.
For a full reference look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield_members.aspx